# Angular Material importando pero no funciona mat-icons

Tags: angular, google-api, angular-material

estoy haciendo un trabajo en angular donde instale angular material de la siguiente forma: `ng add @angular/material`  esto me puso en mi `index.html` la siguiente linea de codigo: `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">`, por lo que entendi de la documentacion es que angular material obtiene los iconos desde Google Material Icons con el nombre y asi es solo que para poderlos usar debo importar el modulo en mi app.module.ts, lo cual hice asi:

```
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     ...
  ],
imports: [
  ...,
  MatIconModule
]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Esto para posteriormente usarlo como: `<mat-icon>priority_high</mat-icon>` dentro de cualquier componente. Pero esto no ocurre asi, ya que se ve de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde se puede observar que solo se escribe el texto contenido en el mat-icons mas no se muestra el icono.

Ahora, segun las peticiones http en el menu de red del navegador en efecto se mandan a llamar las url y regresan correctas con status(200) pero entonces porque no funcionan, sera porque estoy corriendo mi aplicacion en un puerto distinto al 4200?

Comment: lo del puerto no creo que sea el problema si todo lo haces mediante ese puerto ... por que en teoria el acceso a recursos si es `/recurso/...` entendera y resolvera en el mismo puerto ...

Answer (score 2):

Tras tomar como referencia el comentario y comprobar que mis fuentes de google APIs si funcionaban me puse a investigar como funciona material icons, el problema era mas sencillo que la solucion, en mis `styles.css` tenia esta sentencia:

```
*{
   font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif !important;
}
```

Con lo que no contaba era que el icono se generaba con una font-family por lo que esa linea negaba el anterior..! y solo con quitarle el important funciono..!

Comment: ha que bueno que lo encontraste ... esos son errores tipograficos ... aveces una coma o un punto mal puesto y todo explora... en este caso tenia un superposicion de fuentes.